# Trigonometric Equations (Finding angles)

Tags: trigonometry

I am having trouble finding the correct answer to this question:

Find the angles between  $-360^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$ such that $√2 \sin(90^{\circ}-x)+1=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos x=-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}=-\cos45^\circ=\cos(180-45)^\circ$$

$$\implies x=360^\circ m\pm(180-45)^\circ$$ where $m$ is any integer

Find $m$ such that $-360^\circ\le x\le180^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$\sin(90^{\circ}-x)=\cos(x)$ for all $x$

$\displaystyle{-\frac1{\sqrt2}=\cos(135^{\circ})}$ because $180^{\circ}-45^{\circ}=135^{\circ}$

**Remark**

Obviously, those calculations lie on the assumption that angles are measured in degrees. Would you know how to rewrite them using radians ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$√2 \sin(90^\circ-x)+1=0$$
Therefore,
$$\sin(90^\circ-x)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}$$

Taking $\arcsin$ on both sides

$$90^\circ-x=-45^\circ$$

$$x=135^\circ,-135^\circ,-225^\circ$$

in the interval  $-360^\circ\le x\le180^\circ$